# router.navigate not working in async function

Tags: angular, redirect, router

router.navigate dose not work, page didn't redirect to viewer page. But if I add a breakpoint at the last line, is works.

TS:

```
  async onApprove(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.status === true) {
      await this.approveA();
    } else {
      await this.approveB();
    }
    this._router.navigate(['/', 'TaskViewer', this.id]); // Add breakpoint here
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button
        mat-raised-button
        class="approve-button"
        color="primary"
        (click)="onApprove()"
      >
        Approve
      </button>
```

how to successfully redirect to another page in a async function?

Comment: Not *really* an answer to your question, so I'll put it in a comment: If your button is there to navigate to somewhere, make it an `<a>` tag. That's what they're there for. Buttons = actions, anchors = navigation. You can still hook up to the click on the `<a>` and do the approval steps, but ultimately you won't have to worry about async issues with actively navigating. I generally avoid using async in my Angular projects, so I can't give you the definitive answer for the real question.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing `approveA` or `approveB` functions it is hard to know if async is the correct approach here. If `approveA` and `approveB` require awaiting because they call an API endpoint then I personally would migrate to subscriptions and let the `approveA`/ `approveB` functions handle the navigation when the subscription is completed successfully.

However working with the code you have provided I would suggest trying the pattern shown below:

```js
  public async onApprove(): void {
    if (this.status === true) {
      await this.approveA()
        .then((res) => this.handleNavigation()
        .catch((error) => console.error(error);
    } else {
      await this.approveB()
        .then((res) => this.handleNavigation()
        .catch((error) => console.error(error);
    }
  }

  private handleNavigation(): void {
    this._router.navigate(['/', 'TaskViewer', this.id]); // Add breakpoint 
  }
```

Additionally, your function is defined as having a return type of `Promise<void>` but returns nothing, I would normally expect this to throw a compilation error?